# MUI - Change date picker header elements order

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to change the header elements order? I want the arrows to be in the right and left side of the Month-Year title, and not as it is now. The image shows exactly what I'm trying to achieve:

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-butterfly-rkss81?file=/src/App.js
[image: Example]

Do you have any idea how I can achieve it?

I tried to use
`PrivatePickersFadeTransitionGroup` and `MuiPickersCalendarHeader`
class names but it didn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put replace your current style with this one:

```
const dateTimePaperPropsStyles = {
  sx: {
".MuiPickersCalendarHeader-root": {
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyItems: "center"
},
".MuiPickersCalendarHeader-root:first-child": {
  order: 0,
  paddingRight: "20px",
  paddingLeft: "20px"
},
".MuiPickersArrowSwitcher-root": {
  display: "inline-flex"
  // visibility: "hidden"
},
".MuiPickersCalendarHeader-label": {
  textAlign: "center"
},
".MuiPickersArrowSwitcher-spacer": {
  width: "220px"
},
".css-31ca4x-MuiPickersFadeTransitionGroup-root": {
  display: "flex",
  position: "absolute",
  paddingLeft: "80px"
},
".css-9reuh9-MuiPickersArrowSwitcher-root": {
  marginLeft: "-2px"
},
".MuiPickersArrowSwitcher-button": {
  paddingRight: "7px"
}
 }
};
```

[image]

[link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/festive-pine-uv4uy0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: This solution is great, just adding some extra info, in `.css-31ca4x-MuiPickersFadeTransitionGroup-root` you can use 
{
      position: "absolute",
      marginLeft: "auto",
      marginRight: "auto",
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      textAlign: "center" // optional, depends on yout use case
}
To center the datepicker header 'perfectly'

Comment: @zhyp This solution applies styles on desktop, but it doesn't work on mobile, do you know how to apply it to both?

Comment: PaperPRops not working ? Help me

Answer (score 0):

```js
const styleHeaderCalendar = {
  '.MuiPickersCalendarHeader-root': {
    position: 'relative',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  '.MuiPickersCalendarHeader-labelContainer': { marginRight: 0 },
  '.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiIconButton-edgeEnd.MuiIconButton-sizeMedium.MuiPickersArrowSwitcher-button':
    {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      top: '-5px',
    },
  '.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiIconButton-edgeStart.MuiIconButton-sizeMedium.MuiPickersArrowSwitcher-button':
    {
      position: 'absolute',
      right: 0,
      top: '-5px',
    },
};
```

```html
<DateCalendar
          
          defaultValue={dayjs(new Date())}
          renderLoading={() => <DayCalendarSkeleton />}
          slotProps={{
            day: {
              highlightedDays,
            },
            switchViewButton: {
              sx: {
                display: 'none',
              },
            },
            rightArrowIcon: {
              sx: {
                fontSize: '25px',
              },
            },
            leftArrowIcon: {
              sx: {
                fontSize: '25px',
              },
            },
            calendarHeader: {
              sx: {
                '.MuiPickersCalendarHeader-label': {
                  fontSize: '16px',
                  lineHeight: '24px',
                  color: '#202124',
                  fontWeight: 600,
                },
              },
            },
          }}
          slots={{
            day: ServerDay,
          }}
          sx={styleHeaderCalendar}
          onMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
        />
```